# Оптимизация базы данных

Tags: база-данных

Дайте совет. Как можно сделать добавление неограниченного количества фотографий при ограниченных ресурсах сервера? Версии баз данных и каталоги тоже рассматриваются. 
Что-то вроде такого: есть сайт объявлений - я могу дать объявление и загрузить туда неограниченное количество фото. В чем и как их хранить? Как более рационально?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выношу в ответ, быстрее будет)

Таблицы:

```
records: id, name, text, ...
images: id, rid, path, ...
```

Для php+Mysql:

```
$record_id = 15;
$img_id = 20;
$page = 2;
$path = '/images/img20.jpg';
// получить картинки к объвлению:
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM images WHERE rid='.$record_id.' LIMIT '.(15*($page-1)).', 15;');
// добавить картинку к объвлению:
mysql_query('INSERT INTO images (rid, path) VALUES ('.$record_id.', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($path).'\');');
// добавить несколько картинок:
mysql_query(
  'INSERT INTO images (rid, path) VALUES '
  . '('.$record_id.', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($paths[0]).'\'), '
  . '('.$record_id.', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($paths[1]).'\'), '
  . '('.$record_id.', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($paths[2]).'\') '
  . ';'
  );
```

Да, xref - перекрестные ссылки в простонародье. Данные из двух таблиц связываются третьей, содержащей ID из обоих таблиц.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется связь многие ко многим. Реализуется посредством третьей таблици.

Структура примерно такая:

```
announcements:
id | title | ad_text | ....

images:
id | ....

announcement_images:
announcement_id | image_id
```

При добавлении объявления создается запись в announcements. Добавляем также 2 картинки, в результате имеем 3 id, 1 id самого объявления и 2 id картинок. Допустим, id объявления равно 1, а id картинок равно 1 и 2.

В итоге мы должны вставить еще 2 записи в announcement_images

```
1 | 1
1 | 2
```

**UPD:**

Я говорю про создание третьей таблицы для связи картинок с объявлениями. При такой схеме можно загружать неограниченное количество картинок к объявлению. 
А зачем вам отображать сразу 1000 картинок? Установите лимит, например в 10 картинок и пейджер для постраничного просмотра картинок.

Comment: Но тут все равно идет ограничение по количеству. Или вы имеете ввиду создать отдельную таблицу специально для картинок? Которая в свою очередь связана с самим объявлением? Ну, а если я хочу добавить, например, 1000 картинок и при этом их смотреть будет 1000 пользователей? Не кажется вам, что серваку тяжко будет?

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите на верхний багажник лады приоры погрузить Ту-154 и спрашиваете, как это организовать?) 1000 картинок одновременно никто смотреть не будет - это загрузки страницы мин 10 ждать. Но если вас это волнует слабо - вам нужно несколько dedicated server + выделенный (1-10)гигабитный канал. Нормальные люди берут большой хард и постраничную навигацию для картинок. Кстати, третья таблица необязательно - просто таблица images делается `[id|announcement_id|path]`. XRef делается, если картинка может относиться к нескольким записям, а к записям - несколько картинок, в вопросе этого нет.

Comment: Немного не понял. Но напишу, как я понимаю это. Создаем 3 таблицы

Таблица - Объявление
ИД | Техт | id_картинкок

Таблица - катринки
Ид | картинка | ид_объявления

з-я таблица
Ид | ид объявления | ид картинки


Так? Или что-то я не так сделал?

Comment: Всё не так! )

Вы смешали 2 способа.

Если вам не нужно использовать одну и туже картинку в разных объявлениях (а скорее всего не нужно), то используйте способ, который предложил @Sh4dow. Этот способ подразумевает 2 таблицы.

Comment: XRef - что это?
те
Таблица - Объявление ИД | Техт | id_картинкок
Таблица - катринки Ид | картинка 
вот так выходит тогда?????

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю уж тогда 3-й вариант с одной таблицей в базе))

```
records: id, name, text, ...
```

На сервере для каждого объявления создаем папку с названием id из таблице, а при выводе картинок ищем папку с нужным названием и в цикле выводим все картинки в ней. Если надо удалить объявление - удаляем папку и все)

Comment: а как быть с кластеризацией ?

Comment: Ну собственно это у вас /img/ будет второй таблицей, /img/%ID%/ - primary index. А сканирование файловой системы работает дольше запроса к БД. И вообще ФС трогать для структуризации - зло)

Comment: Мой вариант не претендовал на "как надо делать", просто альтернатива уже изложенным) 
[Sh4dow][1]  указал наиболее подходящий, 3-я таблица лишняя.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/465/sh4dow